# Данные из jquery.post

Tags: jquery

Есть вот такой вот post

```
jQuery.post("/gs/mod/modules/map_coord_city.php",{
          city_name : city_n
        },
        function(data){
            CurrentLoc='';
            CurrentLoc=data;

            var Location_coords = CurrentLoc.split(',');
            latitude=Location_coords[0];
            longitude=Location_coords[1];
         } );
```

Мне надо использовать Longitute и latitude за пределами данной функции. Как ими поделиться?

Comment: Можно присвоить их глобальному элементу window, но это минус в карму, так что возможно стоит пересмотреть архитектуру. 

Зачем и когда Вам необходимо использовать эти значения?

Comment: я использую их в разных функциях. В основном для перехода к городу, по координатам, которые я достала, т.е. по этим значениям. Функции вызываются не сразу после поиска координат. в основном по нажатию на определенные кнопки и другие элементы формы

Comment: возможно стоит оперировать неким объектом для города?

Контекст все еще не доконца ясен. Одновременно идет работа с несколькими городами или есть один активный город и информация о нем подгружается этим самым post'ом?

Comment: из нескольких городов активен только один, при смене города инфа о нем подгружается этим post'ом

Comment: возможно стоит создать в глобальной области видимости объект ActiveCity с полями name, latitude, longitude и что там еще?

В функции принимающей ответ сервера надо будет заменить latitude и longitude на ActiveCity.latitude и ActiveCity.longitude

Все еще шероховатый вариант, но уже лучше.

Comment: сделала объект. Делаю вывод ActiveCity.longitude в функции в post'е и за ним, первым выдается вывод за функцией равный первоначальному значению, вторым - в функции - присвоенный результат. Не видит ли он в этих двух местах ActiveCity.longitude как разные переменные?

Comment: если я правильно понял, все работает как надо. Сначала показывается начальное значение, потом, когда приходит ответ на ajax запрос - измененное.

Comment: Первым выходит 0, вторым 76б9. Карта реагирует только на 0

   var currentLocation = ({
  lat : 0,
  lng : 0});
    var city_n = $("#city_listbox").val();
     jQuery.post("/gs/mod/modules/map_coord_city.php",{
              city_name : city_n},
            function(data){
                CurrentLoc='';
                CurrentLoc=data;
                var Location_coords = CurrentLoc.split(',');
                currentLocation.lat=Location_coords[0];
                currentLocation.lng=Location_coords[1];
                alert (currentLocation.lat);    } );
    alert (currentLocation.lat);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Комментарии кончились =(

1. 76б9 третий символ - буква. Это
       ответ сервера или опечатка?
2. Добавьте какую-нибудь кнопку, для
       вывода текущего значения
       currentLocation.lat и перепроверьте
       после отработки ajax
3. "Карта реагирует" контекст в студию,
       если он имеет значение

Comment: 1. Опечатка 76,9
3. в общем в зависимости от полученных координат, должен показываться город. Место показывается исключительно только по начальным значениям, а должно по найденным

Comment: замените запятую на точку

Comment: Sorry. в данных так и есть: 76.9

Comment: как я понимаю, данные ajax'ом получаются корректно и теперь проблема в том, что карта не реагирует. 

Нужен контекст =)

Comment: меня смущают две вещи:
1. То что если этот post убрать, и дать начальные значения, то карта укажет по начальным значениям
2. И то что "0" выводится после тела функции.

Comment: вот я беру данные центра (города который надо показать, тк он активен) из карты гугл


YMaps.Events.observe(map_y, map_y.Events.Move, function () {
   mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(map_y.getCenter().getLat(),map_y.getCenter().getLng());
  });

которые появились так:

 var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(currentLocation.lat,currentLocation.lng);

Comment: 0 выводится после тела функции, потому что, в момент вывода, ajax еще не получил ответ от сервера и новых значений попросту нет.

Только не говорите мне, что изменение центра тоже просто вписано в код после ajax функции...

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
var latitude;

var longitude;

jQuery.post("/gs/mod/modules/map_coord_city.php",{
      city_name : city_n
    },
    function(data){
        CurrentLoc='';
        CurrentLoc=data;

        var Location_coords = CurrentLoc.split(',');
        latitude=Location_coords[0];
        longitude=Location_coords[1];
     } );

function test()
{
    alert(latitude);
}
```

Comment: "global variables are evil" (c)

Comment: В ответ получила:  [object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: попробуйте вывести его в console.log() и посмотрите что там. 
Результат какой-то неожиданный )

Comment: @ikoolik, evil, да, но может быть это пример кода из замыкания?

Comment: в смысле "из замыкания"?

Comment: http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/